# How can I implement a "as" prop with TypeScript while passing down the props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am building a library of components and I need some of them to have a customizable tag name. For example, sometimes what looks like a `<button>` is actually a `<a>`. So I would like to be able to use the button component like so:

```
<Button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</Button>
<Button as="a" href="/some-url">Click me!</Button>
```

Ideally, I would like the available props to be inferred based on the "as" prop:

```
// Throws an error because the default value of "as" is "button",
// which doesn't accept the "href" attribute.
<Button href="/some-url">Click me!<Button>
```

We might need to pass a custom component as well:

```
// Doesn't throw an error because RouterLink has a "to" prop
<Button as={RouterLink} to="/">Click me!</Button>
```

Here's the implementation, without TypeScript:

```
function Button({ as = "button", children, ...props }) {
  return React.createElement(as, props, children);
}
```

So, how can I implement a "as" prop with TypeScript while passing down the props?

Note: I am basically trying to do what `styled-components` does. But we are using CSS modules and SCSS so I can't afford adding styled-components. I am open to simpler alternatives, though.

Comment: This is like 90% there, but for some reason the overload with `T extends ComponentType<any>` is matching things that it shouldn't: https://tsplay.dev/rw2j1w  You could perhaps copy some type declarations from the styled-components package.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very interesting implementation  We will have many components similar to this one so hopefully I'll find a way to make the types reusable. I will look into styled-components and other libraries' definitions. I am ok to go with a more naive approach too at this point.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### New answer

I recently came across Iskander Samatov's article [React polymorphic components with TypeScript](https://itnext.io/react-polymorphic-components-with-typescript-f7ce72ea7af2) in which they share a more complete and simpler solution:

```js
import * as React from "react";

interface ButtonProps<T extends React.ElementType> {
  as?: T;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

function Button<T extends React.ElementType = "button">({
  as,
  ...props
}:
  ButtonProps<T>
  & Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>, keyof ButtonProps<T>>
) {
  const Component = as || "button";
  return <Component {...props} />;
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQdwAdjFlAXlnAEICuMMCEwAKxMKgA8AFThYAHqyYATdNjwwAdAFEANlhBYWUgJ5gsAPjgBvOnBSoA-AC44U+ndwALYDqWUmzphUmmr4AHIQSlj0AL4MBLxM+MBCPPyCTNKyCoYqQeraegZGplwAvOQARulCZOYAFDZ2aAA0tnAanWBiqHQxTu18AkKiEOLS5u0AZHAA8iDAMBKhmgDCJJBMhjCj4gDqi54Q-NgEEy1wANZYxhAEacMiPROTAJTW7bhCqPDr4ELbOAVNBwAA+oKqNSYtHalBgvCgTDgEj+m0BVk6Gm6Y1QMTgAHpzLEGMxWOxOHAAMq4SjIBZMADmQwyu3QTTgBlQqGQDKwLh+UGYDOJdASSRgKSR1Np9KZUMaHKwXJ5XH6VJpOFlzJGPXe7LhCKREmqjzgMFKZTIJoyZDgQlWOmAuEuZSs9XeZUsyD0sHqnO5vNeMXMDqdl0VAEIJPjrUIiX14olkqkAIJgMDuj52A2IuD1dp2CSTOwl5HapjmACSKFIyDgscy+PLxdLZah9ktyFtnkoBEt+Lq1bpKDgjqYl2jzYLJYk5bgPawfbIA6rNbgTAg8DrY8uF1QEHnvbgwHQG63cAAbt7gEo4NiwJOoS3S7P22hXdLNULy3j-SrLQAElgOg6AeADu0C+LahLToWc5-rygHAaBcAQVAUGrsOZ4jqgGp0kK9btvuirKryx6npuI5Xo6t73o+jzPsiMF2K8sRAA)

**Update 4 Apr 2024**: I stumbled upon a new article: [React "as" Prop Using TypeScript](https://www.christianvm.dev/blog/react-as-prop).

### Old answer

I spent some time digging into styled-components' types declarations. I was able to extract the minimum required code, here it is:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

type CustomComponentProps<
  C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>,
  O extends object
> = React.ComponentPropsWithRef<
  C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any> ? C : never
> &
  O & { as?: C };

interface CustomComponent<
  C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>,
  O extends object
> {
  <AsC extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any> = C>(
    props: CustomComponentProps<AsC, O>
  ): React.ReactElement<CustomComponentProps<AsC, O>>;
}

const Button: CustomComponent<"button", { variant: "primary" }> = (props) => (
  <button {...props} />
);

<Button variant="primary">Test</Button>;
<Button variant="primary" to="/test">
  Test
</Button>;
<Button variant="primary" as={Link} to="/test">
  Test
</Button>;
<Button variant="primary" as={Link}>
  Test
</Button>;
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQokscA3nADLAB2A1nAL5wiJcpTwwAtMQCuMLFAkATErTp0YATzBY4AYWmoYJXSUhcsXGAAViYVAB46cPXCwAPOV0XoeWDRAI4ACkAZQANADoASUsoblRgXABRABssEAsYdAAfTCoYCJNwCHNLABUtLHtkLg0APgAaJzgAeVcPC284CAAjACssfDo6uABePPFC0xLMmwg7AHVgGAALbAJHZ112zy7ff0DQyJiYOK4E5LSMyxyJ-Cni0pgK7WrakYB+FwAuOHMAN3kwzgADJmm0QawUKgPr9tvx6AxLPICHgdPpDMZpk9Ni53LsfH4AsFwtFYvFEql0plbthJkUzJkXlUavUms42vjOuhegMhiMWM17ABBVDbLleQkHEnHcnnSlXGlwXJ0+4MmblSpvepjPR1AAUzWcYFsqDhBiMIHVTzmdhFYoarTqzQAlL9VQUPVTrjB7BjLdbZqb7bpHS06nV6Pw1LgSoY4AAhWRGLjmzFW7GZexkHrJkpkR1sf7IOI1GC-Mgm0AljRkAQjcb6k3zVAusYjQ3Oey5mAp1gRAfNuyCAD0zpdiPsSd7JTgxdLllGlbiIBrZDqZSwhnsI+nKcjdCnea4c5LwDLS6rq6gtbgRiXI7khnXzU3hkPu+PB6PM5P8-Pi7LtWN51mgowsJwvCCPeZCPluMAvs4b4wB+e4lN+aF-meF5Adet5gRB3A8PwzpIfBqFfvQQA)

I removed a lot of stuff from styled-components which is way more complex than that. For example, they have some workaround to deal with class components which I removed. So this snippet might need to be customized for advanced use cases.

Comment: No need for `extends React.ElementType` in interface ButtonProps. Use nullish: `as ?? "button"`. No need to import React anymore. No need to specify children in the props?

Comment: @tanguy_k Could you explain why "No need for extends React.ElementType in interface ButtonProps" ?

Comment: doesn't work with `forwardRef`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Gabin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66568474/22480471), and with a little inspiration from the [Chakra UI source code](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/core/system/src/system.types.tsx), I wrote my own generic version which allows you to use the `as` prop anywhere you want without repeating too much boilerplate:

```
import { ComponentPropsWithoutRef, ElementType } from "react";

export type As = ElementType;

export type MergeWithAs<Component extends As, Props extends object = {}> = Omit<
  Props,
  "as"
> & { as?: Component };

export type ComponentPropsWithAs<
  Component extends As,
  Props extends object = {},
> = Omit<
  ComponentPropsWithoutRef<Component>,
  keyof MergeWithAs<Component, Props>
> &
  MergeWithAs<Component, Props>;
```

Here's an example of it in action:

```
import clsx from "clsx";

import { As, ComponentPropsWithAs } from "../types/ComponentPropsWithAs";

interface TextContainerProps {
  className?: string;
}

export default function TextContainer<Component extends As>({
  as,
  className,
  ...props
}: ComponentPropsWithAs<Component, TextContainerProps>) {
  const Component = as ?? "div";
  return (
    <Component
      {...props}
      className={clsx("max-w-[70ch] mx-auto px-4", className)}
    />
  );
}
```

I haven't been able to get it working with `React.forwardRef`, but y'all are welcome to try.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can make the same thing with JSX.IntrinsicElements. I have Panel element:

```
export type PanelAsKeys = 'div' | 'label'
export type PanelAsKey = Extract<keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements, PanelAsKeys>
export type PanelAs<T extends PanelAsKey> = JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]
export type PanelAsProps<T extends PanelAsKey> = Omit<PanelAs<T>, 'className' | 'ref'>
```

I omitted native types like ref and className because i have my own types for these fields

And this how props will look look like

```
export type PanelProps<T extends PanelAsKey = 'div'> = PanelAsProps<T> & {}

const Panel = <T extends PanelAsKey = 'div'>(props: PanelProps<T>) => {}
```

Then you can use React.createElement

```
return React.createElement(
  as || 'div',
  {
    tabIndex: tabIndex || -1,
    onClick: handleClick,
    onFocus: handleFocus,
    onBlur: handleBlur,
    onMouseEnter: handleMouseEnter,
    onMouseLeave: handleMouseLeave,
    'data-testid': 'panel',
    ...rest
  },
  renderChildren)
```

[image]

I see no ts errors in this case and have completions for label props like htmlFor