# Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm trying to convert from this code in pure JavaScript

```
export const Container = ({
    as: Element = 'div',
    children,
    className,
    ...rest
}) => {
    return (
        <Element
        {...rest}
        className={`px-5 w-full max-w-screen-md m-auto ${className}`}
    >
        {children}
    </Element>
  )
}
```

to TypeScript

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export const Container = ({
  as: Element = "div",
  children,
  className,
  ...rest
}: {
  as: string;
  children: ReactNode;
  className: string;
  rest: any;
}) => {
  return (
    <Element
      {...rest}
      className={`px-5 w-full max-w-screen-md m-auto ${className}`}
    >
      {children}
    </Element>
  );
};
```

And get the error message as below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un5wK.jpg

I dont quite understand what the message was about. Please explain that for me.

I tried to change the type but not work.

Comment: From where `Element` is coming?

Comment: It passed down through as props

Comment: I meant, is `Element` an external library component, a custom one? Can you show it?

Comment: It just an custom Element that pass to the return statement right below, for example I can create an Container witth "as" props equal "nav" and then it will return a <nav></nav> element

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer, it related to the "as" prop.
Its type should be React.ElementType.

Found the answer inside this thread.
[Implement "as" prop in React component in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549938/implement-as-prop-in-react-component-in-typescript?fbclid=IwAR0Yb_LDa0sz7mdjH9rZeA9yHpV9P3gT1wCL40Ykz21KoAv7ZyO5mJcPbxg)